# Is there a way to upload file to google drive from remote url - C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Basically, I have some videos on a remote server that I want to upload to google drive without downloading them to the client. Just directly upload them to google driver. I read the [google drive api .net documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) and some questions here on stackoverflow but they don't mention anything of that sort. At least in the questions I have read. I am doing this on a .net framework windows forms application.

Comment: Hi, can you show your code example?

Comment: I haven't yet started in the google drive code. I am seeing first if what I want is possible because if it is not, I might not use google drive.

Answer (score 0):

For the upload to work you need to have the file on the machine that is running the code. You are going to have to download them to yourself first then upload them to google drive.

```
{
    // Create the service using the client credentials.
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "APP_NAME_HERE"
        });
    var uploadStream = new System.IO.FileStream("FILE_NAME",
                                                System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                                                System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
    // Get the media upload request object.
    InsertMediaUpload insertRequest = service.Files.Insert(
        new File
        {
            Title = "FILE_TITLE",
        },
        uploadStream,
        "image/jpeg");

    // Add handlers which will be notified on progress changes and upload completion.
    // Notification of progress changed will be invoked when the upload was started,
    // on each upload chunk, and on success or failure.
    insertRequest.ProgressChanged += Upload_ProgressChanged;
    insertRequest.ResponseReceived += Upload_ResponseReceived;

    var task = insert.UploadAsync();
    task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            // Remeber to clean the stream.
            uploadStream.Dispose();
        });
}

static void Upload_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress progress)
{
    Console.WriteLine(progress.Status + " " + progress.BytesSent);
}

static void Upload_ResponseReceived(File file)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Title + " was uploaded successfully");
}
```